# differences between mysql on linux vs windows

Tags: mysql, windows, linux

Recently, My Company's considering to purchase an application using MySQL. the consultant offers two options :

1. running the apps and mysql server on windows 2008 server, or
2. run the mysql server on linux an the apps on xp virtual machine

I was wondering if anyone could help me get the picture right. My Questions are :

1. are there really differences on performance between MySQL running on linux and Windows server? I've browsed for some views, but have found different opinions. If there are some differences, what causing them?
2. what key aspect that affect the performance for a mysql  server running on windows xp or windows 2008 server? I mean I don't need the server configuration stuff anyway, right?

( My team has been working with both windows and linux servers, so no problem with the capabilities issue ).

Thank you for helping. :)

Comment: this isn't a programming question. Should be on serverfault.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong forum. My Mistake.. I'll be more carefull in the next posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question for which you will not receive an absolute right or wrong answer, as it is left to subjective opinions based on user experience, that's why people are voting to close it.

However, to assist you, I would recommend that you use MySQL on Linux. There are a number of reasons why Linux is a better choice over windows, but some of the big ones are; security, stability, and total operating costs. Granted, with Linux it may be more complicated to set-up configs and daemons to ensure your server is running properly, but in the end, it is worth the setup.

To decide which OS on which to develop the app depends on your dev shop's code expertise and experience. If they can finish the better project in a shorter duration using windows, then that's what you should opt for.

Comment: thank you for the reply.So Sorry about the wrong forum. My Mistake..

Comment: No worries, SO is great, but does have a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

The main diference is that the filenames created on linux are case sensitive, whereas the files on Windows are not.

Here's an excerpt from [the relevant documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) regarding cas sensitivity.

> By default, table aliases are case sensitive on Unix, but not so on Windows or Mac OS X. The following statement would not work on Unix, because it refers to the alias both as a and as A:
>       `SELECT col_name
>       FROM tbl_name AS a
>       WHERE a.col_name = 1
>       OR A.col_name = 2;`
>   However, this same statement is permitted on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is a pain, but the apps might have a better quality on Windows 2008 server, than on XP. Or later on a newer Windows version. MySQL should pose less differences on both platforms. So how much better will the apps do under Windows 2008 server?

Maybe maintenance (XP!), maybe support for specific MS technologies.