# Running Mysql 8.0 on windows server and Ubuntu - Comparison

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, ubuntu

I would like to get some opinions on the comparison to install Mysql 8.0 in Windows Server and Ubuntu.

A lot of people recommend to run MySQL 8.0 on Linux/Ubuntu platform for better performance. In general, is there any performance degradation running Mysql 8.0 in Windows server?

Where can I get some reference on the comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

I found this other SO post. [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661345/differences-between-mysql-on-linux-vs-windows) I personally prefer Linux because there is less overhead in general as an operating system. They don't call it the LAMP stack for nothing, you know?